# When I try to delete a Django user, I get “DatabaseError: no such table: auth_message”

Tags: django, django-authentication

I’m creating a Django website that uses the bundled auth app to create user accounts.

During development, sometimes I want to create user accounts and then delete them. However, when I try to delete a user account using the Django shell, I get the following error:

```
DatabaseError: no such table: auth_message
```

The code is running on a server with Python 2.5 and Django 1.2.1. I wrote the code (and ran `syncdb`) on my local machine, which is running Python 2.6 and Django 1.4 alpha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've added:

- `django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware` and `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` to the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in your settings.py file
- `django.contrib.auth` and `django.contrib.messages` to the INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py file

If that doesn't work, it's possible you've somehow messed up your database, and if you don't have too much information already stored you could try clearing it and remaking it using `python manage.py syncdb`

Comment: Yup, I’ve got those. (I think they were in there by default, but they’re definitely in there now, and I did a clean `syncdb`.)

Comment: Although the code is running on a server with Python 2.5 and Django 1.2.1, but I wrote it (and ran syncdb) on my local machine, which is running Python 2.6 and Django 1.4 alpha. I could imagine that could lead to a database/code mismatch on the server.

Comment: Whoa...big difference between Django 1.2.x and 1.4... Is the app itself written for Django 1.4 and Python 2.6?

Comment: Yup, although I haven’t (as far as I’m aware) been using any 1.4-specific features, and everything else seems to work fine. I can’t imagine this will work in the long-term though, so I think I’d better get 2.5 and 1.2 running locally.

Comment: Although creating the database by running `syncdb` on the server works as a workaround for now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the database on the server too?  You said you created the database on your local machine, is the server using your local machine as its database? If not you need to create the tables `syncdb` on your server too.

Comment: Yup — the database is an SQLite 3 file, and I‘ve uploaded it to the server.